# Is it possible to Install Xamarin.iOS on a mac without Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am trying to configure my mac for iOS development. I followed the instructions on the "***setting up your mac for iOS development***" video and downloaded the unified installer.

However, when I run the installer, it asks me which components I want to install. I unchecked Andriod and Mac and only left iOS checked. When I clicked continue, the installer is then asking me where do I want Android SDK installed. Well, I don't want it at all.

Is there a way to configure both the mac and Visual Studio to **only** install Xamarin.iOS. I don't have an andoid device so installing its SDK and NDK is just pointless, unless , they are required by Xamarin to function.

Thank you,

Comment: If you don't plan on using Android why not just stick to Xcode?

Comment: because I am a .NET developer and I think it would be a lot easier for me to write c# code than swift, even though, swift is actually pretty easy to learn. also you didn't really answer my question :)

Comment: To the question, I would probably contact Xamarin's support or file a bug at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/. That would definitely seem like a bug in the installer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can, follow this guide in the Xamarin Documentation to just install the products you need

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/mac/manual_installation/

Also if you need the mono runtime you can grab it from

http://www.mono-project.com

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried that link however, it is very outdated. If you actually go to the dashboard from your xamarin account, there are two options when you unhide -> download the unified installer or download Xamarin Studio. there are no options to download separate modules. Not on the Mac at least. On the windows side, you can still download the MSI.

Comment: Oh, I do see the download options for all products as listed on the link above, but it must be because I do have a Xamarin Subscription. I guess what you can do is let the Xamarin installer run and then just uninstall the android bits https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/uninstalling_xamarin/#Uninstall_Xamarin.Android This is not a pretty solution but should do what you want while Xamarin provides that option on the installer

Comment: yea, either that or just leave it there. Who knows, maybe one day I will decide to learn Android development :)